# React, dynamically add text to ref span

Tags: reactjs, ref

I'm trying to render a message to a span tag specific to an item in a list. I've read a lot about React 'refs', but can't figure out how to populate the span with the message after it's been referenced.

So there's a list of items and each item row has their own button which triggers an API with the id associated with that item. Depending on the API response, i want to update the span tag with the response message, but only for that item

When the list is created the items are looped thru and each item includes this

```js
<span ref={'msg' + data.id}></span><Button onClick={() => this.handleResend(data.id)}>Resend Email</Button>
```

After the API call, I want to reference the specific span and render the correct message inside of it. But I can't figure out how to render to the span at this point of the code. I know this doesn't work, but it's essentially what I am trying to do. Any ideas?

```js
if (response.status === 200) {
    this.refs['msg' + id] = "Email sent";
```

Comment: why not use `state`??? `if (response.status === 200)` `this.setState({...})`

Answer (score 3):

I recommand using state. because string refs legacy (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)

```js
const msgs = [
    { id:1, send:false },
    { id:2, send:false },
    { id:3, send:false },
];

this.state = {
    msgs
};

return this.state.msgs.map((msg, index) => {
    const status = msg.send ? "Email Sent" : "";
    <span>{ status }</span><Button onClick={() => this.handleResend(index)}>Resend Email</Button>
});

async handleResend (index) {
    const response = await callAPI(...);
    if(reponse.status !== 200) return;

    const newMsgs = _.cloneDeep(this.state.msgs);
    newMsgs[index].send = true;
    this.setState({
        msgs: newMsgs
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is set `innerText`

```js
   this.refs['msg' + id].innerText = "Email sent";
```

But rather than using `ref` try to use `state` to update elements inside render.

Comment: Yeah, i thought about state, but wasn't sure how to reference the item using state

Answer (score 0):

i was facing with this issue right now and i figured it out this way:

```
// currentQuestion is a dynamic Object that comes from somewhere and type is a value
const _target = `${currentQuestion.type}_01` 
const _val = this[`${_target}`].current.clientHeight // here is the magic
```

please note that we don't use `.` after this to call the ref and not using `refs` to achieve what we want.

i just guessed  that `this` should be an Object that would hold inner variables of the current object. then since `ref` is inside of that object then we should be able to call it using dynamic values like above...

i can say that it worked **automagically!**